# Nesting spring form tags with <c:if> tags

Tags: forms, tags

My current  jsp contains a some radiobuttons like this:

```
<input type="radio_1" value="1" id="radio_1"
<c:if test="${account!=1}">disabled</c:if> 
<c:if test="${account==1 && radio_1=='1'}">checked</c:if>/>
```

I have need to convert it to form tags of spring framework so that i can bind it to a model bean.Whole purpose of doing this is  binding error messages to the fields. So i converted it to spring form tags 
Something like this:

```
<form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" 
<c:if test="${account!=1}">disabled</c:if>
<c:if test="${account==1 && radio_1=='1'}">checked</c:if>/>
```

But seems we can not nest form tags like HTML tags So i get error message "unterminated tag".
But i need to attach those those  tags and dont want the  original functionality to be changed.
Do we have some alternatives to this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using c:if only at the disable attribute, use it at the radiobutton tag as well

```
<c:if test="${account!=1}">
  <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" disabled/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${account==1 && radio_1=='1'}">
  <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" checked/>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${account==1 && radio_1!='1'}">
 <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" />
</c:if>
```

or

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${account!=1}">
      <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" disabled/>            
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${account==1 && radio_1=='1'}">
      <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" checked/>    
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
      <form:radiobutton path="radio_1" value="1" />                          
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```